# Yaml : failed at splitting arguments, either an unbalanced jinja2 block or quotes

Tags: shell, ansible, yaml, sh, ansible-template

Tried everything but cannot figure that one thing out, please suggest

```
- name: Formate the report  
shell: |
  cd /opt/disk1/tmp/
  sed -i '1s/^/Table_Name Table_Category Status\n/' "extract_summary.txt"
  column -t -o '     ' "extract_summary.txt" >> "Record_count_summary.txt"
  chmod 777 "Record_count_summary.txt"
  awk '/FAIL/' Record_count_summary.txt > Record_count_fail.txt
  chmod 777 "Record_count_fail.txt"
  echo "-----------------------**** Record mis-match for below tables ******-----------------------------------------------" >> "Record_count_summary.txt"
  cat "Record_count_fail.txt" >> "Record_count_summary.txt"
  sed -i '1s/^/--------------------*** Record count for conformed tables in hive Vs S3 ****-------------------------------------\n/' "Record_count_summary.txt"
  sed -i '2 a\\' "Record_count_summary.txt"
register: report_formatting
```

The error is :

{
"reason": "failed at splitting arguments, either an unbalanced jinja2 block or quotes: cd /opt/disk1/tmp/\nsed -i '1s/^/Table_Name Table_Category Status\n/' "extract_summary.txt"\ncolumn -t -o '     ' "extract_summary.txt" >> "Record_count_summary.txt"\nchmod 777 "Record_count_summary.txt"\nawk '/FAIL/' Record_count_summary.txt > Record_count_fail.txt\nchmod 777 "Record_count_fail.txt"\necho "-----------------------**** Record mis-match for below tables ******-----------------------------------------------" >> "Record_count_summary.txt"\ncat "Record_count_fail.txt" >> "Record_count_summary.txt"\nsed -i '1s/^/--------------------*** Record count for conformed tables in hive Vs S3 ****-------------------------------------\n/' "Record_count_summary.txt"\nsed -i '2 a\\' "Record_count_summary.txt"\n\n\nThe error appears to be in '/tmp/awx_1078157_sqp25u94/project/tenants/W0002/playbooks/task_table_reconcile_hive_s3.yaml': line 61, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: Formate the report\n    ^ here\n"
}

Comment: `Tried everything` <= even testing your lines one after the other to find out the one that is faulty?

Comment: It might be a better idea to just put this into a Shell script (`.sh` file) and run it using [script module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/script_module.html). This way you can also test/debug your commands independent of Ansible.

Comment: The error references `line 61, column 5` and explicitly tells us that it may be elsewhere in the file. The first line you show seems to be line 61, so you need to show us more context.

Comment: @seshadri_c , thank you for the suggestion. I made a script and that runs fine.